# Can't install elementary OS to SSD

Tags: system-installation

elementary OS installer does find my SSD ("install alongside another OS"), but I can only install to HDD.
Windows isn't installed to HDD, Microsoft is located in C:\Windows (SSD).

[image]

I'm now shrinking, but I get an error. Am I doing everything right?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could it be that you've created 4 primary partitions on the ssd already? That would lead to inability to create a new partition on the drive. Update your post with a screenshot from windows disk manager, and output from elementary installation (just open terminal and type "fdisk -l" command over there)

Comment: I haven't created partitions at least on purpose, I've tried to avoid that and let the distro installer do the job.

Comment: Dolphin I had to rejec tyour edit because it wasn't technically correct. You're talking about free space on a system partition (disk C), but in terms of HDD partitioning your disk is full - your  system partition covers entire disk, there is no space to create new partition. So idea is to downsize "SYSTEM" partition to be able to create new partition. Please read about volumes/partitions on Wikipedia to get more idea about the matter.

Comment: Also if you want to communicate - leave a comment, do not edit the answer you've received

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understood properly. I'll try downsizing. How can I see the size of the system partition?

Comment: @Dolphin I don't understand this question. First you say "*elementary OS installer doesn't find my SSD*", then "*elementary still detects that Windows is installed*" and finally "*Windows isn't installed to HDD, Microsoft is located in C:\Windows (SSD)*". So if Windows is installed in your SSD and elementary is detecting it, then it is clearly detecting you SSD.

Comment: @Dolphin windows disk manager shows total disk capacity on a left, and a partition size on each partition created. Total size is 223,58. There is 200Mb reserved space and 223,38Gb partition (System C:), they together use 100% disk capacity

Comment: @Gabriel I can't install elementary to my SSD, that's a better way to describe this issue.

Comment: Dolphin try to decrease space you shrink by 100-200 Mb. Sometimes space calculated for shrinking is not quite accurate and you should decrease a bit shrinking space.

Comment: Thank you @ V_Pavel, that worked. Now there's ~ 32 GB of "unallocated" space, is that OK? Am I ready to install?
Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/IYGR0og.png

Comment: @Dolphin yes, now it should be ok to give it another run ;) 32 Gb is not really much but would be sufficient for system files. you can install fuse and 3g-ntfs later to access your user files on a HDD, and to store them to avoid filling up space on your elementary partition. But that is a whole different question.

Answer (score 1):

@Dolphin, thanks for the follow-up with a screenshot. Yep I can see there are only 2 partitions present, definitely not 4 :) But what about free space? As I can see from your screenshot your disk C is completely used up, there is no free space to create new partitions that is why I suspect it doesn't show up SSD disk in partitioning - there is no free space to create a new partition.

You need to downsize disk C if that's possible. You can use some tools like Paragon partition magic, not sure what soft is the best pick nowadays, haven't used this for a while...

Comment: I think you meant to post this as a comment since it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I think you didn't read the answer since it does answer the question. OP doens't have free space on his SSD -> it doesn't show up in partitioning process. Solution - to downsize his system partition to create a new space for elementary

Comment: Actually, I posted this comment before you made the edit to the answer. I removed my downvote now that I saw that part.

Comment: Although I accidentially posted the answer too soon I believe it was pretty much clear even before the edit. The fact there is not enought space was clearly outlined

Comment: @V_Pavel what do you mean by "your disk C is completely used up"? For what I can see there are over 70 Gb of free space.

Comment: @Gabriel system partition has free space, but SSD has partition covering it completely, leaving no space for new partitions

Comment: Yes I see that, but selecting "install along another OS" should make the installer automatically resize the NTFS partition to make space for elementary, right?

Comment: @Gabriel, nope. It just means that Windows partitions will not be erased during partitioning. Not a single installer will attempt to downsize the partition - it's just too heavy task